# Too many clicks on scroll arrow is calling a function that closes the overlay

Tags: javascript

The bug here is that when I click very quickly or many times, on the overflow:scroll; arrows, the navigator call the function below, that removes the mouseover and closes the dropdown. 
This part ->  event.target.classList.add('mouseover');
is being executed when the bug appears. Because the too many clicks are forcing the function to execute. How can I stop this from being called on the wrong time?

```
function comportamento_menu_hover()
 {



var elems_li = document.querySelectorAll('.topo-3 ul li');

for (var i=0;i<elems_li.length;i++)
{
    elems_li[i].className += ' ativo';
}

var el_botoes = document.querySelectorAll('.topo-3 > ul > li');
var el_lv2 = document.querySelectorAll('.lv2');

/*alteracao pra pegar somente os 3 primeiros elementos */


for (var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    el_botoes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', add_el_hover);
    el_botoes[i].addEventListener('mouseout', remove_el_hover);
}
for (var i=0;i<el_lv2.length;i++)
{
    el_lv2[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', add_el_hover);
    el_lv2[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', remove_el_hover);
}


function add_el_hover(event)
{
    //event.preventDefault();
    //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('nao chamou scroll home');
    event.target.classList.add('mouseover');
    var el_bg_hover = document.querySelector('.bg-hover-menu');
    if (!el_bg_hover)
    {
        elem_bg_hover = document.createElement('div');
        elem_bg_hover.className = 'bg-hover-menu';
        document.querySelector('#header .wrapper').appendChild(elem_bg_hover);
        verifica_scroll_home();

        var el_section = event.target.querySelector('section');
        if (!el_section)
        {
            var el_section = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('section');
        }

        var el_secoes = document.querySelectorAll('.lv2 section');
    }

    if (!el_section){return;}

    if (el_section.className.indexOf('anime')==-1)
    {
        for (var i=0;i<el_secoes.length;i++)
        {  
            if (el_secoes[i] != el_section)
            {
                el_secoes[i].className = el_secoes[i].className.replace(/anime/g,'');
            }
        }       
    }
    el_section.className +=" anime";      

}

function remove_el_hover(event)
{
    /*event.stopPropagation();*/
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log('propagation stopped 2');
    event.target.classList.remove('mouseover');
    var el_bg_hover = document.querySelector('.bg-hover-menu');
    if (el_bg_hover)
    {
        el_bg_hover.parentElement.removeChild(el_bg_hover);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It will be nice if you can make a snippet where you can demonstrate the problem

Comment: it is only happening on chrome

Comment: that is a good information, but what I wanted to say is click on `edit` focus on the body of the answer do `ctrl+m` then create a demo